# Using React Native & Relay, can I have multiple root containers in my app?

Tags: react-native, relay

I'm trying to use Relay and React Native together.

From my experience so far, I'm forced to create a new RootContainer for every single page I send to the Navigator component.

Is this correct?

Or should there only be one RootContainer that accepts new components/RelayRoutes ? I don't see a way to make this possible from what I tried so far.